# How do JVM build tools resolve dependencies with no identified version in the POM?

Tags: maven, gradle, sbt, pom.xml

My project has a transitive dependency on Google's guice library.

Guice's POM contains dependencies that have no version info. For example:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I note that there is only one version of that particular library: `1`.

I also note that there is no `<dependencyManagement>` node in the POM. There is a `<parent>` node, but its version ( `4` ) does not match `javax.inject`'s version.
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/4.0/guice-4.0.pom

So my question is:

How do build tools like `mvn`, `gradle`, and `sbt` determine (programatically) which version to download? (eg, `1`. Given the lack of info.)

If you know the answer, is it officially documented anywhere?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a link to the guice POM. I don't believe that there is neither dependencyManagement nor a parent POM.

Comment: @JFabianMeier, I have corrected my post as you requested. There is, in fact, a `<parent>` element, but its version is not the same as `javax.inject`'s version. So do you known how build tools resolve the URL of the `javax.inject` jar to download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version is defined in the dependencyManagement of the parent POM.

Here you find the parent POM:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice-parent/4.0/guice-parent-4.0.pom

If the version is missing, it comes from a parent POM, an imported BOM or dependencyManagement. In some cases, it may be hard to figure out the exact place because there may be a hierarchy of parent POMs and/or BOMs.

Maven never "guesses" the version of a dependency. For plugins, this is different. A missing version will lead to Maven downloading the newest version of the plugin it finds in the defined repositories.